# Apache Management Web Console

Tags: php, apache, configuration, httpd.conf

I have a Apache/PHP web server. Is there any web based management tool to configure Apache server? **I need to use this to configure httpd.conf file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webmin will do this: http://www.webmin.com/.  Plus you can use it to configure a whole host of other services:  bind, mail, mysql, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for cPanel at http://cpanel.net/ . You will be able to manage all server services, however Webmin is good alternative too.